# How to add a Figure in header embedded in an interrupted line?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How do I add a figure in my header that will look like this, where the line at the bottom of my header starts on the left is 1 cm long has a gap of 3 cm for the figure and the line continues for the remaining length:

-- figure -----------------

I have a line running using this code in my .cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test-report}
\newif\if@print
\LoadClass[10pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
\def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
\colorlet{title}{black}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\titlefont\thepage}
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{\color{title}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}
```

And my text file:

```
\documentclass{test-report}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

some text

\end{document}
```

ps. I'm using sharelatex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be better if you add a full compilable example.

Comment: Still `\titleshape` undefined

Comment: I think it is sorted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following will help a bit

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
\colorlet{title}{black}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\titlefont\thepage}
    %% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
    \fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    %% Section name on the right (odd) page.
    \fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{\color{title}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}%
      \rule{1cm}{\headrulewidth}%
      \raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering%
          \ifdim\headrulewidth>0pt\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}\fi
      }}%
      \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm\relax}{\headrulewidth}%
    }%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}
\makeatother

%% enlarge headsep and headheight
\geometry{headsep=2\baselineskip,headheight=20.5pt}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\noindent some text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
\colorlet{title}{black}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\titlefont\thepage}
    %% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
    \fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    %% Section name on the right (odd) page.
    \fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{\color{title}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}%
      \rule{1cm}{\headrulewidth}%
      \smash{%
        \parbox[b]{3cm}{\centering%
          \ifdim\headrulewidth>0pt\includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}\fi
      }%
      \rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm\relax}{\headrulewidth}%
    }}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}
\makeatother

%% enlarge headheight
\geometry{headheight=20pt}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\noindent some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think this solves my problem! Aligning the bottom of the image with the line is the only thing I need to find out how to do.

Comment: @Jasper See my updated answer.